# Delay `ssh-add` passphrase prompt until first use

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I would like `ssh-add` to delay asking for the passphrase to my private key(s) until they are first accessed.  The reason for this is that I would like to start `ssh-agent` on login and add keys to it, but I don't always use SSH, so I want the keys locked until and unless I actually need to start SSHing.

I have not been able to find any mention of anything like this in my Googling.  Is there a way to do this?  How do I keep my SSH keys locked until I actually need them?

Answer (score 3):

The AddKeysToAgent option will function as needed. 
Setting this option on the command line (`-o AddKeysToAgent=yes`) or in your SSH config file (`~/.ssh/config` → `AddKeysToAgent yes`)
will automatically add your SSH keys, as you use them,
to the running SSH agent. 
This will have the effect of deferring the password prompt
and unlocking of keys until you actually use them.

Example:

```
Host example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Documentation from the [`ssh-config(5)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ssh_config.5.html#:%7E:text=system%2Dwide%20files).-,AddKeysToAgent,-Specifies%20whether%20keys):

> `AddKeysToAgent`
>
>   Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running
>   ssh-agent(1). 
>   If this option is set to
>   `yes`
>   and a key is loaded from a
>   file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent
>   with the default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1). 
>   If this option is set to
>   `ask`
>   , ssh(1) will require confirmation
>   using the SSH_ASKPASS program
>   before adding a key (see ssh-add(1) for details). 
>   If this option is set to
>   `confirm`
>   , each use of the key must be confirmed,
>   as if the
>   `-c`
>   option was specified to ssh-add(1). 
>   If this option is set to
>   `no`
>   , no keys are added to the agent. 
>   ... 
>   The argument must be
>   `yes`
>   ,
>   `confirm`
>   ,
>   `ask`
>   , or
>   `no`
>   (the default).

Thanks to BasketCase on #openssh on Freenode.